# Проверка переменной на число в php

Tags: php

Есть выражение:

```
<?php
    $age = 'ghjjdyuj';

    if ($age<18) {

        echo "Вы ещё молоды";
    }

    elseif ($age<0 && !is_numeric($age)) {

        echo "Возраст не определён";
    }

    else {

        echo "Вы уже пенсионер";
    }

?>
```

Не могу понять почему выводит "Вы ещё молоды". Как добиться вывода "Возраст не определён" ?

Comment: ну так напишите `if (!is_numeric($age) || $age <= 0) {

        echo "Возраст не определён";  return;
    }` в начале, чтоб не пропускать дальше

Comment: спасибо, да, разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы лучше так сделал:

```
$age = 'ghjjdyuj';

if(!empty($age) && is_numeric($age)) {

   if($age <= 18) {

      echo 'Вы еще молоды!'; 

   } else 

   if($age  >= 55) {

       echo 'Вы уже пенсионер!'; 

   } else {

         echo 'Вы еще в самом соку!'; 

   }

} else {

    echo 'Ошибка! Не возможно определить  Ваш возраст'; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern='/^\d+$/';
$res=preg_match($pattern, $age);
if($res){
   echo('здесь только циферки');
}else{
   echo('тут кажется не только циферки');
}
```

кстати... если это возраст... то можно использовать и

```
$pattern='/^\d{1,2}$/';
```

не думаю что найдется кто-то кто живет трехзначными годами )))

Comment: на счет трехзначных - это вы зря, надо учитывать все граничные случаи. Плюс не так уж мало людей возраста 100+